# Save Picture Stored in PictureBox to Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to save a picture displayed in `PictureBox` in MS Access, in my case I don't want to use `OpenFileDialog` method (its work fine for me). Its just I want to store into the database the default pic showed in `PictureBox1` when the software starts. The issue is: its stores a black image in the database and I can see it when retrieve the image and show it in `PictureBox`.

Part of Code:

```
Private Sub saveimage()
    Try
        
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytImage = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()
        
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you tagged SQL Server when you've stated MS Access.

Comment: Thanks to @Dale K  for noticing, I *kind of* missed that. `Private Function SaveImage(img As Image) As Byte()  dim ms as new MemoryStream() img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat) return ms.ToArray() End Function`. Call it as `dim imageBytes = SaveImage(PictureBox1.Image).` Save `imageBytes` to the DataBase.

Comment: See the [following project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/tree/master/ReadInsertingImages) which loads a image into a PictureBox then goes and inserts that image into MS-Access.